# ¿Hay algún equivalente en castellano al inglés "TL;DR"?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, jerga-internet

En muchos textos virtuales se lee **"TL;DR"** (o en minúsculas, **`tl;dr`**). Se trata de las iniciales de la frase "Too long; didn't read" utilizada como cabecera de un texto muy largo para resumir su contenido en un par de frases.

¿Tenemos en castellano algún equivalente? "Demasiado largo, no lo leí" parece la traducción más directa, pero me gusta pensar en algo que vaya más al origen de la expresión del tipo "Resumen" o "Resumiendo".

Otras variantes a tener en consideración podrían ser:

[image]

Comment: ¿Por qué no "En resumen"?

Comment: Suena bien, @Flimzy Sin embargo, dado que "en resumen" se suele utilizar como partícula al final un texto y resumirlo, verlo al prinicipo se me hace "raro".

Comment: Aunque no se usa de forma escrita (al menos no la he visto), hay una frase que yo uso a menudo que parece ser equivalente a TL;DR;: "Para hacerte el cuento largo corto...". Pongo esto en comentario porque OP quiere una forma escrita.

Comment: "En breve". Quizás equivalente a "Abstract" en inglés. O también, si son textos técnicos, "Resumen/Informe/Respuesta ejecutivo", que se acostumbra a ubicar al principio de un informe largo.

Comment: Yo creo que "TL;DR" entra en la misma categoría que "FAQ", por ejemplo, o tantas otras. En español de España, no hay mucha costumbre de traducir este tipo de abreviaturas, quizás porque adoptamos anglicismos con mucha facilidad. "P+F" (Preguntas más frecuentes) no tiene la misma aceptación que "FAQ" (Frequently Asked Questions). "en breve", "en resumen", etc. son las traducciones correctas de otras expresiones inglesas (In summary, In short...). La "gracia" de "TL;DR" es la expresión en sí. Si la traducimos por "En breve" o "en resumen", la gracia queda lost in translation.

Comment: En breve me parece lo mejor, resumen es muy literario y como dices va al final.

Comment: Yo agregaría de todas formas que es complicado pretender que alguien la comprenda. Cuando se quiere poner un resumen de algo se utiliza "algo algo algo (...) como seguía lo importante (...) una breve conclusión". Creo que si se busca la gracia, no se va a encontrar. Si se busca la finalidad es mejor poner "En resumen (dos puntos o coma)" o utilizar "(...)" para decir que había contenido que no importa (o el autor no quiere mostrar)

Comment: @scubaFun Eso parece una traducción directa del inglés *To cut a long story short*. Yo, al menos, no la había visto nunca hasta ahora en español.

Comment: Yo diría lo que dijo Flimzy, `En resumen`.  Pero también, puede usar `En corto`... no?

Comment: Yo generalmente no ando muy al tanto con el habla del internet, así que en esta situación diría, al comienzo, "Versión corta: [una frase] // Versión larga: [varios párrafos]."

Comment: @Gorpik - Pero "to cut a long story short" no se pone directamente al principio, sino en medio de la historia, para poder saltar algunos detalles.

Comment: Perdón, fedorqui, ¿quién se supone que va a decir TL:DR?  El que está o no está leyendo lo que A escribió?  ¿O sería A mismo?  Yo creo que A, para hacer más accesible lo que escribió.

Comment: @aparente001 efectivamente, _TL;DR_ lo dice la persona que escribe el texto a modo de encabezamiento.

Comment: @aparente001 Mi comentario solo dice que esa frase que propone scubaFun parece un calco de una expresión habitual inglesa relacionada. No la propongo como alternativa española en absoluto; de hecho, no me gusta.

Comment: @Gorpik - cuando dices *calco de una expresión etc.*, ¿quieres decir *un equivalente* de la expresión en inglés?

Comment: @aparente001 Me refiero a una expresión copiada palabra por palabra (o casi) de otro idioma.

Comment: @Gorpik - Me gusta.  Es interestante, no he encontrado una palabra para expresar eso en inglés.

Comment: @aparente001 En inglés, es, simplemente, *calque* (este caso concreto sería un *phraseological calque*).

Comment: @Roberto ¡Eso es; exactamente! Traducirlo, en este caso, es como explicar un chiste. O se escribe así (y ahí está la gracia) o no se traduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La mayoria de acrónimos (OMG, WTF, WP, ec), por no decir todos, tienen origen inglés, de manera que es muy complicado encontrar un sustituto de un acrónimo al español.

Lo que sí se puede hacer es desplegar y traducir el acrónimo, ver su significado en su lengua original y traducirlo o adaptarlo a otra.

En tu caso, tl;dr, como bien has dicho viene a decir (*too long; didn't read*), que viene a decir literalmente: demasiado largo, no lo he leído.

Según he podido leer, tuvo un origen despectivo, refiriéndose a que si un mensaje o párrafo era demasiado largo, el destinatario no lo iba a leer por ser demasiado largo. Con el paso del tiempo, el significado ha evolucionado, para referirse a un breve resumen antes de un párrafo largo, que desarrolla la idea introducida en dicho resumen.

Se podría extender, como bien has dicho, a resumen, sumario, cabecera o similares.

Fuente: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read

Answer (score 11):

No tiene tanto alcance como la forma en inglés, pero es cada vez más común en los foros de internet ver la expresión **RPV** (resumen para vagos)

Comment: ¿Tienes algún enlace a un ejemplo? Me parece una opción muy buena y coherente con otras usuales en internet en español.

Comment: Por ejemplo, http://www.mediavida.com/foro/off-topic/mv-abogados-denuncio-361828

Answer (score 2):

Desde mi experiencia como usuario de internet en español, como respuesta ante un texto largo el equivalente mas parecido sería "ni con tus ojos". Como forma de decir que vas a hacer un resumen, simplemente se dice "Resumen:" y se pone el resumen en negrita. No me consta que exista un acrónimo como tl;dr en español, de hecho se suele usar tl;dr como respuesta a un texto largo