# ¿Cómo se pueden partir las direcciones URL entre líneas de un texto?

Tags: ortografía

A más de uno le habrá pasado alguna vez que ha tenido que intercalar una URL particularmente larga en un texto, ya sea en línea con el resto del mismo o en un párrafo separado específico para la dirección.

En el caso de dichas URL largas que necesiten más de una línea para ser escritas, ¿cómo se puede partir la URL?

Ejemplos:

```
http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17145/
podr%C3%ADa-un-hispanohablante-actual-entenderse-bien-con-uno-del-pasado

http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17145/podr%C3%ADa-un-
hispanohablante-actual-entenderse-bien-con-uno-del-pasado
```

Parece que algunas alternativas podrían ser el usar las barras o los guiones ya presentes en la dirección, pero ¿y si no los hay?

```
http://short.url/podr%C3%ADaunhispanohablanteactualentenderse-
bienconunodelpasado
```

Supongamos que la dirección no incluye el guión que actúa como separador en la URL, ¿sería válido? ¿Se entendería o se tendría escribir de otra forma? ¿Opina la RAE algo al respecto?

Comment: Me sorprendería que la RAE tenga criterio al respecto, pues es algo más técnico que estilístico. Para mí, en estos casos aplica el [PEP de Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10739843/1983854) o lo que digan las publicaciones que pudan contenerlas: [Referencing - APA 6th: URLs](http://aut.ac.nz.libguides.com/APA6th/urls) _Don't break a long URL at http:// when it runs across two lines. When the URL is long DO break it across two lines before a slash (/) or other punctuation_

Comment: Dicho lo cual, yo creo que lo suyo sería marcar con una barra invertida, de modo que quede claro que continúa sin ningún otro carácter adicional.

Comment: Por cierto ya estás en el [podio histórico](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language) por reputación, ¡qué carrera tan meteórica, enhorabuena!

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @fedorqui: una URL no es más que una serie de símbolos, pero no forma palabras ni estructuras lingüísticas.

Comment: Si no hay ningún separador por el cual cortar la URL en mi opinión no se debería poner nada, saltas a la línea siguiente sin más. @fedorqui no entiendo lo de la barra invertida

Comment: @blonfu me refiero a lo que se ve por ejemplo [aquí](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23801489/1983854). Es decir, usar un carácter como la barra invertida ``\`` para separar las líneas que deje claro que es un simple separador y no parte de la cadena. Del tipo http://ww.... \  ...sigue... blabla... \.

Comment: @fedorqui, ah vale. Lo malo que si es una URL local de Windows podría confundirse con el separador de directorio. Aunque si es, como parece, la forma convenida de identificar que un código va en la misma línea supongo que debe escribirse así

Comment: Si usas Latex puedes usar el paquete url para dividir la URL

Comment: ¿Es esta una pregunta acerca del español? ¿Cómo lo hacen los otros idiomas?

Comment: @Rodrigo es una pregunta acerca del español, porque el español tiene sus propias normas para dividir palabras, y quería saber si la RAE dice algo acerca de usar dichas reglas en una URL (siempre que sea posible).

Comment: @fedorqui ¡gracias! La verdad es que me alegra haber encontrado este sitio: me siento a gusto aquí, siento que puedo ser útil y que puedo aprender mucho, y me alegra haber conocido gente con la que hablar del tema que nos ocupa.

Comment: No me parece que una URL sea español. Empezando porque si lo fuera se llamaría algo como LRU, además no es una palabra con sílabas, ni una sigla. Es más bien un pedazo de código que entienden los programas para acceder a lugares en la internet. Además una URL dividida no sirve de nada.

Comment: @DGaleano las URL de este mismo sitio contienen muchas palabras en español, al igual que las de muchos blogs escritos en nuestro idioma, por lo que podrían ser susceptibles de dividirse de alguna forma.

Comment: @DGaleano tampoco importa si una URL es español o no en si misma porque puede formar parte de un texto que sí este en español. Es como si yo pregunto como se escribe una palabra en inglés dentro de un texto en español: en cursiva, entrecomillada... El criterio a seguir se aplica según las reglas del español

Comment: No lo creo. El hecho de que entendamos parte de la URL no la hace español y la prueba está en que tienen segmentos como %C3% y %20% para reemplazar cosas que si son español por cosas que entienden mejor las máquinas. Yo entiendo que %20% es el ascii 32 lo que representa un espacio pero, otra vez, que se entienda no lo hace español. Para mi una URL es código de computador. Nosotros no hablamos URL pero los programas si las entienden. Mi recomendación es si el texto va a usarse de manera digital usar hipervínculos para no ver la parte de código y si va a imprimirse no dividirla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues parece que la RAE sí que tiene [algo que decir al respecto](http://aplica.rae.es/orweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=fGagUkJpJzxmEdkr):

> En el caso de que sea necesario dividir una dirección electrónica, deberá hacerse coincidir la partición con una barra separadora, dejando esta en la primera línea y sin insertar ningún guion, ya que este elemento podría considerarse parte integrante de la dirección:
>
> ```
> Encontrará más información en http://www.museodelprado.es/  
>   educacion/educacion-propone/
> ```

(Extraído de la "Ortografía 2010", epígrafe 4.1.1.1.3, página 410.)

Comment: Interesante, yo no he sido capaz de encontrar eso. Aún así no responde a tu duda en el caso de un texto muy largo sin separadores.

Comment: [TL;DR](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15317/1674) usa un sistema de acortar direcciones del tipo goo.gl o tinyurl : D

Comment: @blonfu no me imagino un texto como el que propone la RAE de ejemplo si la URL fuera un galimatías de letras y números y no fuese fácilmente entendible.