# ¿Qué mecanismos tiene el español para "neologismear"?

Tags: verbos, neologismos

**TL;DR:** ¿Qué mecanismos tiene el español para la formación de nuevos verbos?

Acabo de oír la siguiente expresión:

> ...es que fulano me ha **bronqueado** y no quiero que vuelva a pasar...

Con independencia de que en español exista el verbo *[abroncar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0BhLcFn)*, me hace mucha gracia cuando alguien se inventa un verbo de esa manera. La propia RAE define el sufijo *-ear* como:

> **[-ear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIeaLdH)**
>
> 1. suf. Forma verbos derivados de sustantivos o adjetivos, rara vez de pronombres. *Humear, falsear, tutear.*

Es decir, se provee un mecanismo para generar verbos a partir de sustantivos. Hay algunos, como los que menciona la definición, que están aceptados por la RAE e incluidos en el diccionario, pero eso no impide que en el habla coloquial se puedan formar nuevos verbos, como *googlear* (buscar en Google) o el propuesto *bronquear* (echar una bronca).

Sin embargo, de repente me resultó curioso que no se puedan formar verbos usando *-eer* o *-eir*, siempre son acabados en *-ar*. Estaría bien saber por qué esto es así, pero de momento vamos a otra pregunta: ¿qué mecanismos tiene el español para *neologismear*? ¿De qué otras formas se pueden inventar verbos en nuestro idioma?

Comment: TL;DR o... [RPV](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15883/1674) :)

Comment: Si el sustantivo termina en -ción, regularmente el verbo derivado termina en -cionar (sin descartar que haya excepciones). No debe ser dificíl, por lo mismo, encontrar ejemplos de neologismos verbales por esa vía. También he oído eficiente -->*_eficientar_. Dudo que se pueda dar una respuesta _completa_, en todo caso...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer existe [verbolog](http://www.verbolog.com/inventar.htm), una web que te permite inventar verbos. La [lista](http://www.verbolog.com/neolog.htm) contiene términos tan interesantes como *empenumbrecer*, *bisabuelizar*, *grisnublar*...

Además, dicen que Frida Kahlo decía en una carta datada en 1947:

> ¿Se pueden inventar verbos? Quiero decirte uno: Yo te cielo, así mis alas se extienden enormes para amarte sin medida.

Sin duda, una manera muy sugerente de crear verbos: *cielar*...

[image]

Centrándonos en la parte más formal del debate, existen distintas maneras de acuñar nuevas palabras:

> - agregar afijos.
>
>   - sufijos: fama > fam*oso*, fruta > frut*ero*
>   - prefijos: feliz > *in*feliz.
> - agregar, a un sustantivo o adjetivo, ciertos sufijos específicos: humano > human*izar*.
> - agregar interfijos entre la raíz y el sufijo: pintarrajear (pint + arr +  -aj + -ear).
>
> Sufijos específicos para formar verbos:
>
> ```
> Sufijo  Ejemplos
> -------------------------------
> -ar     activar, alegrar
> -ear    blanquear
> -ecer   florecer
> -ificar amplificar, identificar
> -izar   escolarizar, localizar
> ```
>
> Ejemplos de verbos con interfijos:
>
> ```
> Verbo        Composición
> -------------------------------------
> bailotear    bail + ot- + -ear
> despanzurrar des- + panz + urr- + -ar
> apretujar    apret + -uj + -ar
> resquebrajar res- + quebr + -aj + -ar
> patalear     pat + -al + -ear
> corretear    corr + -et + -ear
> ```

Anotaciones tomadas de [Formación de nuevos verbos por derivación](http://elblogdegramatica.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/formacion-de-nuevos-verbos-por.html).

Answer (score 2):

No tengo buenas fuentes a mano en este momento (puedo añadir más tarde) pero con respecto específicamente a que los verbos se formen exclusivamente con la conjugación en *-ar*, la respuesta es que ya desde el latín la primera conjugación era la que contaba con más verbos y era la más productiva en la formación de nuevos verbos, por simple analogía: al pensar cómo conjugar un nuevo verbo, el hablante recurre al más frecuente de los modelos existentes. Más todavía, esto funciona en otro nivel: una vez que se derivan unos cuantos verbos nuevos usando un determinado sufijo, queda tácitamente establecido que otros sufijos deben funcionar de la misma manera.

Entiendo que en el español hoy la terminación *-ar* es la única productiva, y que lo mismo ocurre en francés con la correspondiente (*-er*). Esto hablando de verbos derivados por medio de sufijos, por supuesto (ya que no hay razón para no inventar algo como *maldigerir*).